# Play 2.3.8 - Unable to start Kamon 0.4.0

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-monitoring

I am actually trying to integrate Kamon 0.4.0 with my play (scala) application (Great framework by the way!).

Here is what I did:

1. Added the following dependencies in my *build.sbt*:

   ```
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
         jdbc,
         anorm,
         "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "2.4.0",
         "org.bouncycastle" % "bcpkix-jdk15on" % "1.51",
         "org.bouncycastle" % "bcprov-jdk15on" % "1.51",
         "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.8.0",
         "io.kamon"    %% "kamon-core"           % "0.4.0",
         "io.kamon"    %% "kamon-play"           % "0.4.0",
         "org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver"         % "1.8.6"
       )
   ```
2. Starting and shutting down Kamon in Global.scala:

   ```
   object Global extends GlobalSettings {

     override def onStart(app: Application) {
       val hsmProxyName = Play.current.configuration.getString("ngocspd.hsm.proxy.name").get
       val supervisorName = Play.current.configuration.getString("ngocspd.ocspd.supervisor.name").get
       val notifierName = Play.current.configuration.getString("ngocspd.notification.name").get
       java.security.Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider)
       // Starting Kamon
       Kamon.start()
       Akka.system.actorOf(Props[NotificationActor], name = notifierName)
       Akka.system.actorOf(Props[HardwareSecurityModuleProxyActor], name = hsmProxyName)
       Akka.system.actorOf(Props[OCSPdActor], name = supervisorName)
     }

     override def onStop(app: Application) {
       Kamon.shutdown()
     }
   }
   ```
3. Starting activator with the path of the AspectJ agent:

   ```
   activator -J-javaagent:/Users/pantin/.ivy2/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar
   ```

I am encountering two problems.

When running the app, the following exceptions are thrown:

```
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'scala.concurrent.impl.Future.PromiseCompletingRunnable' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.concurrent.impl.Future.PromiseCompletingRunnable not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'scala.concurrent.impl.Future.PromiseCompletingRunnable' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.concurrent.impl.Future.PromiseCompletingRunnable not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'scala.concurrent.impl.Future.PromiseCompletingRunnable' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.concurrent.impl.Future.PromiseCompletingRunnable not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'scala.concurrent.impl.Future.PromiseCompletingRunnable' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.concurrent.impl.Future.PromiseCompletingRunnable not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'scala.concurrent.impl.Future.PromiseCompletingRunnable' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.concurrent.impl.Future.PromiseCompletingRunnable not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'scala.concurrent.impl.Future.PromiseCompletingRunnable' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.concurrent.impl.Future.PromiseCompletingRunnable not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'akka.event.Logging.LogEvent' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.Logging.LogEvent not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'akka.event.Logging.LogEvent' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.Logging.LogEvent not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'akka.event.Logging.LogEvent' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.Logging.LogEvent not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'akka.event.Logging.LogEvent' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.Logging.LogEvent not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
[error] o.a.w.b.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.LazyExecutorServiceDelegate not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:418) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:392) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:477) [aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
```

Is there a way to get rid of these exceptions?

And then, the application crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ConfigurationException: Could not start logger due to [akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded [akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger] due to [java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot retrieve extensions while Kamon is being initialized.]]]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:166) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
Caused by: akka.ConfigurationException: Could not start logger due to [akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded [akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger] due to [java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot retrieve extensions while Kamon is being initialized.]]
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$class.startDefaultLoggers(Logging.scala:144) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar:na]
    at akka.event.EventStream.startDefaultLoggers(EventStream.scala:26) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.init(ActorRefProvider.scala:622) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:619) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:616) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

The response at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kamon-user/Wz1hVypO15E was helpful.

Instead of using activator run to run the play application in dev mode, after running sbt stage I used

```
target/universal/stage/bin/my-app -J-javaagent:fullPathToAspectJ/aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar
```

Please note that using activator start did not work.

Answer (score -1):

There exist a sbt plugin that allow perform LTW in sbt and we will be able to do run in development mode in play seamlessly. [sbt-aspectj-runner](https://github.com/kamon-io/sbt-aspectj-runner).